# Ignore global variable webpack4/babel7

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I've recently upgraded to webpack4/babel7 - and a 3rd party script is getting "incorrectly" compiled.

before

```
import {window} from 'service' // abstraction
window.foo = window.foo || {}, window.foo.bar = foo.section 
// foo implicitly on window...
```

after minification

```
var o; = // webpack window alias...
var n; // scope variable declared...
var foo = o.foo || {}
o.foo.bar = n.section 
// TypeError! cannot read section of undefined 
// should be o.foo.section?
```

I'm struggling to understand what is happening.
Either the minification is causing the variable declaration, or webpack is being helpful. I can get round this by editing the 3rd party script, but that's not a strategy I want to pursue.

Can anyone either suggest some config magic to either ignore this file or prevent the declaration of this variable?

Answer (score 0):

The option I needed to disable was **inline**, as webpack (terser by proxy) was encountering the free variable and scoping it.